# Partial Residual plots for Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial Models?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, partial-plot

I am looking for guidance on how to create partial residual plots for zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB) models in R. I am quite new to R and have done a lot of research on my questions but have not found any solutions yet.

I am modeling abundance for a species and I am using an offset (i.e. TotalNets) to account for sampling effort. I have also scaled my Moon variable (sMoon), where Moon = the percent moon illumination. PrePost is a categorical variable describing Pre-Post disturbance with three levels - Pre, Post1 and Post2. CloudCover is also categorical with three levels - 0=clear, 1=partly cloudy, 2=cloudy. Here are my models/code.

**ZINB Model**

```
mod1 <- 
   zeroinfl(MOMO ~ offset(log(TotalNets)) + PrePost + sMoon*CloudCover,  
              data=abundance1, dist='negbin')
```

And here is the output of the model:

[image]

I understand that it is hard for zero-inflated models to calculate confidence intervals but that *ggeffects* should work with *zeroinfl* models. When I run the *ggeffects* code I get an error and it won't plot the model (code below).  The error has to do with my offset variable missing but I do not know how to fix this. Any suggestions are appreciated as I need these graphs for a paper.

```
plot1a<-ggpredict(mod1, terms=c("PrePost2"))%>%
data.frame() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x, predicted))+
geom_pointrange(aes(ymax=conf.high, ymin=conf.low))

*Error: Confidence intervals could not be computed.
* Reason: "argument \"offset\" is missing, with no default"
* Source: offset(log(TotalNets))*
```

If you require more information please let me know, this is the first time I have posted a question.

Comment: what do you need to plot? If you use ggpredict, you are plotting the predictions while holding the other variables constant, although i am not so sure about the offset

Comment: if you want to plot the coefficients, you can use something like sjPlot, but it will convert the coefficients with a log

Comment: I need to plot the predicted values for each explanatory variable while holding the other variables constant as you mention. I have tried  ggpredict (from ggeffects) and plot_model (from SjPlot) but both give me the same error message regarding the missing offset. If I remove the offset it works so it definitely because of the offset but I don't know if there is a way around that using code?

Comment: It looks like the developer fixed the offset issue for zeroinfl and ggeffects, but it is still not calculating CI's

Comment: So the issue no is that it doesn't have a confidence interval? did you check whether your model returns a standard error? I cannot tell where the error is coming from

Comment: Yes the output of the model is returning Std. Error. I have added the output of the model to the original post. Whatever the problem with CI's is, also applies to plot_model (SjPlot). I am able to make a plot with plot_model whereas it won't even plot with ggpredict; however, no CI's are plotted

Comment: Hey i tried and also checked out github..  zeroinfl doesn't work well with ggpredict when there's an offset and a "|" that separates the zero from non-zero. you need to calculate the error yourself or if you want an approximate, you can put log(TotalNet) as a variable

Comment: This is not ideal, but in my opinion , unless I know what the package does to estimate the error, i would not put it in a paper

Comment: I got fed up using zeroinfl and have rerun the models with glmmTMB. Everything seems to be working fine now. I am able to use ggpredict and it gives me CI's so I have fixed my problem. Thanks for all your suggestions.